# How can I change every http to https using JavaScript in source code?

Tags: javascript, http, https

I would like to change every instance of http to https using JavaScript. How can I do this? what would the source code look like?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Changing anything via JS could be disabled by merely switching off JS in the browser. If you want to force your site/application to change all links to use SSL then you should do it in the source on the server, or if it's on Apache, then you could redirect using a .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I assume what you are after is in  tags, but it should be easy to extrapolate this to others:

```
if (document.location.protocol === 'https:') {
    $('a').each(function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if (href.indexOf('http:') > -1) {
            href = href.replace('http:', 'https:');
            $(this).attr('href', href);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can throw https change request to servlet in http domain page, and server will redirect to https domain page. Trying to change domain from http to https in javascript will cause browser security error(as cross domain requests are denied in all modern browsers).
I solved the same problem as shown below.

```
function readyForSecure(loginID)
{
   if (location.protocol == 'http:') {
   // https change request
      HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit.call(document.getElementById('login-box'));
   }
}


<form id="login-box" action='xxxxxx' method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
   ...
   <input type="button" value="Login"  onfocus="readyForSecure(this.value)"/>
</form>
```

you can refer here.  [refer page.](http://www.noiden.co.kr/techstory/Page.do?titleLink=Switching-from-HTTP-to-HTTPS-with-javascript-when-log-in&articleId=58&accountId=dreamingduck)

Answer (score -1):

You can redirect http traffic to https in JavaScript with something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
<!-- begin hide
function httpsRedirect()
{
var httpURL = window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname;
var httpsURL = "https://" + httpURL;
window.location = httpsURL; 
}
httpsRedirect();
// end hide -->;
</script>
```